# GSON Array to go

Tags: android, json, android-studio, gson

I'm thinking about it, but I can't print the **name and age of the json Crospromotion** on the console. I'm using the GSON library, but I'm stuck right now and I don't know how to move forward.

**I have my JSON**

```
    {
        "crospromotion": [
            {
              "name": "Orus",
              "age":14
            },
            {
              "name": "Michelle",
              "age":29
            },
            {
              "name": "Jack",
              "age":29
            }
          ],
          "totalAccessorios": 20,
          "totalCaras": 20
    }
```

**My JSon controller class:**

```
public class Data {    
  private Crospromotion crospromotion;    
  private int totalAccessorios, totalCaras;
        
    public int getTotalAccessorios() {
         return totalAccessorios;
    }
        
    public int getTotalCaras() {
         return totalCaras;
    }
        
}
```

**Class Crospromotion:**

```
public class Crospromotion {
    private String nombre;
    private int edad;

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public int getEdad() {
        return edad;
    }
}
```

**MainActivity:**

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
final Data data = gson.fromJson(myResponse, Data.class);
Log.d("MEN: ", data.getTotalAccessorios());
// I want to print in Log, the fields Crospromotion: name and age. But I don't know how to continue.
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just forgot to add a getter for your Crospromotion field in your `Data` class?

```
public class Data {    
  private List<Crospromotion> crospromotion;    
  private int totalAccessorios, totalCaras;
        
    public int getTotalAccessorios() {
         return totalAccessorios;
    }
        
    public int getTotalCaras() {
         return totalCaras;
    }     

    public Crospromotion getCrospromotion() {
         return crospromotion;
    }
}

...

Log.d("MEN: ", data.getCrospromotion().getAge());
```

Btw, it looks like the fields in your JSON don't match your `Crospromotion` class. GSON uses reflection to match json fields to members of a class. You can use `@SerializedName()` to map JSON field names to member fields if the names differ.

For example:

```
public class Crospromotion {
    @SerializedName("name") private String nombre;
    @SerializedName("age") private int edad;

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public int getEdad() {
        return edad;
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't display the LOG. 
I get the following error:  (java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.Object java.util.List.get(int)' on a null object reference)

Comment: looking at your json crospromotion is actually an array, gson returns null when your json doesn't match your class, I've updated the sample code for the Data class

Answer (score 0):

The attributes in the json string have different names than in the class Crospromotion. So you can just change the property names of the Crospromotion class like this:

```
public class Crospromotion {

    private String name;
    private int age;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
}
```

Also in the json string you have an array of Crospromotion instances, but in the data class you only have one instance. That means you have to change the json string or write the class like this.

```
import java.util.List;

public class Data {
    private List<Crospromotion> crospromotions;
    private int totalAccessorios, totalCaras;

    public int getTotalAccessorios() {
        return totalAccessorios;
    }

    public int getTotalCaras() {
        return totalCaras;
    }

    public List<Crospromotion> getCrospromotions() {
        return crospromotions;
    }
}
```

You also didn't have a getter for the Crospromotion List. Therefore you couldn't access it, because the property was private. With this code you should be able to access the data that you want to access.

Comment: I get the following error: (java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.Object java.util.List.get(int)' on a null object reference) I'm inside my MainActivity and I just put the following: private Crospromotion crospromotions; Log.d("Bucle: ", datContDss.getCrospromotions().get(0).getName());

Comment: I changed the name of the Crospromotion List in the Data class, but I didn't tell you to change the name in the json string. That's why the value of the List is null. You have to either change the name of the List in the Data class to 'crospromotion' or change the property name in the json string to 'crospromotions'.